# factory design pattern verifying understand

Tags: java, design-patterns

I would like to verify whether my understanding is correct.

Let's say I have class Car and 2 subclasses SuperCar and ClassicCar.

If I make a method to create those 2 subclasses within a CarFactory and I am invoking them as follows - CarFactory.make("super") for SuperCar and CarFactory.make("classic") for ClassicCar, I am using a simple factory right?

If I want to use a factory method I would need to make CarFactory an abstract / interface that has make() method. Then I should have other Factory such as DefaultCarFactory for example to create a default car and override the make() method and ModifyCarFactory to create a modified car which also override the make() method and in this case this both methods still returning a type based on the parameter that I give whether it is "classic" or "super"

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It is important that you add your code to better understand your question

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on the *classic* and *super* discriminators.

Take a look at the below snippets.

**Your Car hierarchy:**

```
public class Car {...}

public class ClassicCar extends Car() {...}

public class SuperCar extends Car() {...}
```

**The Factory definition:**

```
public interface CarFactory {

    // it is imperative the return type here is `Car`
    Car getInstance();

}
```

**The Factory implementations:**

```
public ClassicCarFactory implements CarFactory {

    @Override
    public Car getInstance() {
        return new ClassicCar();
    } 

}

public SuperCarFactory implements CarFactory {

    @Override
    public Car getInstance() {
        return new SuperCar();
    } 

}
```

**Your client code:**

```
public class CarClient {

    private CarFactory factory;

    // inject a ClassicCarFactory or a SuperCarFactory via constructor 
    public CarCient(CarFactory factory){
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void doSomethingWithCar() {
        // get either a ClassicCar or a SuperCar based on the concrete factory type
        Car car = factory.getInstance();
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: so in the main if i call
CarClient x = new CarClient(SuperCarFactory)
let say doSomethingWithcar() return the car 

then if i say x.doSomethingWithCar()  
x will be supercar obj am i right?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you pass a `SuperCarFactory` into `CarClient` and then invoke `doSomethingWithCar`, the car instantiated in `doSomethingWithCar` will be of type `SuperCar`.